# .empty() makes the HTML page jump/twitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the `jQuery(".bokningar ul").empty();` to empty the specific `div` when new content arrives with Ajax. The only problem I get is that the HTML page jumps/twitches a little bit if the window isnt scrolled all the way up. 
My code:

```
       jQuery(".bokningar ul").fadeOut(500);
       jQuery(".bokningar ul").empty();
                var data = data.d.results;
                var items = [];
                jQuery.each(data , function (index, value) {

                    items.push(`
                             <li><span class="date">${moment(value.EventDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}</span>
                             <span id="${value.ID}" class="edit">Ändra tid</span>
                             <span id="${value.ID}" class="erase">Radera tid</span></li>
                            `);

                });
                jQuery(".bokningar ul").append(items.join('')).hide().fadeIn(700);
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Comment: its the size if the object appended my suggestion would be to make the <ul></ul> with minimal height and width :)

Comment: This is my ul class: `ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }` How can i make it more minimal?

Comment: Or you mean the whole content of the `ul`?

Comment: do it like this 
the number:<300> is an Example you can put the number you see fit  
ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0;min-height: 300px; min-width: 300px; }

Comment: It twitches back and forth now, first up and the down to the postion is came from

Comment: your problem is not the the jquery its in the css you need to make the <ul></ul>
fixed

Comment: fixed it, I set the parent elemt of `ul` to `min-height` and then it stays put. thanks for your help!!!

Comment: no problem Can u mark my Answer please ?

Comment: yes if you post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is not the jquery its in the Css Try To make the 
"height and width" be fixed